approval_state is not set when trying to add google login
I'm trying to add google login to my website. I tried both the login button and the one tap experience. both result in the following error in the console.
[GSI_LOGGER]: Parameter approval_state is not set correctly.
I searched everywhere and couldn't find a root cause.
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async></script>
<div id="g_id_onload" data-client_id="xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
data-login_uri="http://localhost:5173">


I had this issue as well and was freaking out because this thread is literally the only resource that comes up if you Google Search "Parameter approval_state is not set correctly.".
So I tried using use useGoogleLogin and got a more verbose error - Application used only for internal Access blocked: ProjectName can only be used within its organization.
I believe that just like me, you are trying to log in with a different email than the one you set up your Google Cloud Project/Oauth Client IDs.
To fix this, I opened my Google Cloud Project selected the specific project and navigated to OAuth consent screen. Under User type, you should click "Make External". You will be prompted to pick a publishing status - I selected Testing and add the email I was using to log in under the "Test Users" section.
After that it worked flawlessly!
Edit: You must add your localhost domain + port under Authorized JavaScript origins and Authorized redirect URIs - in my case, this was the setup:
Google Client ID Authorized URIs

I was pulling my hair out! this ^^ is the answer that worked. Thank you @Cainã Perotti Barbosa!

The port you're using (5173) likely doesn't match the Authorized JavaScript origins and redirect URIs configured in your Google Cloud Console.
Change your application to run on port 3000 instead of 5173. Or if you need to use a different port, update your Google Cloud Console settings accordingly.

The place you may need to go is  https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials.  From there, find your key under "OAuth 2.0 Client IDs".  Click on the edit button (pencil icon) on the right side of that key.  Check your origins and redirect URIs.

I resolved the issue by adding the origin(http://localhost:port) under Web Credentials > Authorized JavaScript Origins.

I had this trying to test on localhost.
You might need to run your local development server with HTTPS. For Next.js, it's next dev --experimental-https.
